# C# асоциативные массивы

Tags: c#

получаю предположим такие данные

```
       id name value
       1  name    1
       2  name    2
       3  name2  NaN
       4  name2  NaN
       5  name3  10
       6  name4  NaN
```

я хочу получить массив всех имен где значение NaN. если пробежаться по списку и делать add то получу дубли. как получить набор уникальных имен и id

то есть что хочу получить

```
      array = ['name2' => [3,4],
               'name4' => [6]  ]
```

таким образом получается я затираю айдишники

```
     var NonValueArray = new Dictionary<string, double>();

        for (int i = 0, cnt = c.Count; i < cnt; i++)
        {
            logger.Trace(c[i].id + " " + c[i].value + " " + c[i].server);
            if (Double.IsNaN((c[i].value)))
            {
                //NonValueArray.Add(c[i].service, c[i].id);
                NonValueArray[c[i].service] = c[i].id;
            }
        }
        foreach (var pair in NonValueArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pair.Key);
        }
```

Comment: обновил ответ, Вам необходимо подключить пространство имен

Comment: обновил ответ, ошибка была в отсутствии закрывающей скобки:) попробуйте сейчас должно работать

Comment: Учебник C# в руки и не загромождать sor пустыми вопросами.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko с подобной формулировкой можно закрыть любой (или почти любой) вопрос

Comment: @Bald56rus, нет, не любой. В данном конкретном случае речь идёт о незнании элементарных вещей, которые изучаются по учебникам. Такие вопросы на StackOverflow — верный путь к снижению качества сайта. Если на них не реагировать, через пару-тройку лет здесь будут процветать вопросы студентов, ленящихся прочитать учебник.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var grouped = array.GroupBy(x=>x.Value).ToList();

foreach(var g in grouped)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1}", g.Key, g.Count()));
}
```

писал без студии возможны ошибки

что бы пользоваться  `linq` необходимо подключить соответствующее пространство имен `using System.Linq;`

пример [здесь](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cnqg57)

Comment: можно комментарии?

Comment: @des1roer конечно

Comment: Ошибка "System.Array" не содержит определения для "GroupBy" и не был найден метод расширения "GroupBy", принимающий тип "System.Array" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку)

Comment: InitParam.Param[] s = c.ToArray();
       
            var grouped = s.GroupBy(x => x.service).ToList();
            foreach (var g in grouped)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1}"), g.Key, g.Count());
            }

Comment: Индекс (отсчитываемый от нуля) должен быть больше или равен нулю, но меньше размера списка аргументов.

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас есть плоский список сущностей, то результирующий словарь можно получить следующим образом:

```
var result = entities
    .Where(_ => Double.IsNaN(_.Value))
    .GroupBy(_ => _.Name, _ => _.Id)
    .ToDictionary(_ => _.Key, _ => _.ToArray());
```